# Openmotif isn't available in RHEL-7. Motif is available. Has anyone evaluated the implications?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

Up until now, we have used RHEL-6 and OpenMotif was available in the default yum repo.  In RHEL-7, I now see that "motif", which I believe is not open source, is available in the yum repo.  Just curious to know what others have done relative to licensing.  Have you purposely stayed with openMotif? Or picked up the Static Libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motif is licensed under the LGPL v2.1 [according to their website](http://motif.ics.com/) and the source is available on [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/motif/).  In both Fedora and RHEL 7, 
the motif package obsoletes the openmotif package, so it's basically just a package rename.  There is also a virtual provides so running `yum install openmotif` will resolve to the motif package.

Comment: Yes it does resolve to `motif`. I was wondering as he said the implications... For instance, even if `motif` is installed, a software needing `openmotif` will look for it but not `motif` right ?